# Creating graph with recharts with multiple data arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, recharts

Hello I am trying to create  something similar to the question [React Recharts- getting data from different array names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604153/react-recharts-getting-data-from-different-array-names/42343067) but I cannot display the data on the graph.

This is my data set:

```
[ {0: {t: "00:00", value: 0.000957}, 
   1: {t: "03:00", value: 0.000853},
   2: {t: "07:00", value: 0.004372},
   3: {t: "09:00", value: 0.001052},
   4: {t: "13:00", value: 0.001013},
   5: {t: "16:00", value: 0.000854},
   6: {t: "18:00", value: 0.000861},
   7: {t: "22:00", value: 0.004468}},
  {0:{t: "00:00", value: 0.000185},
   1: {t: "03:00", value: 0.00011},
   2: {t: "07:00", value: 0.000236},
   3: {t: "09:00", value: 0.003084},
   4: {t: "13:00", value: 0.000132},
   5: {t: "16:00", value: 0.000108},
   6: {t: "18:00", value: 0.000136},
   7: {t: "22:00", value: 0.000308}}
]
```

The code:

```
export interface Props  {
    data: any;
}


export class MyGraph extends PureComponent<Props>{
state={
    data: {}
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<Props>, prevState: Readonly<{}>, snapshot?: any): void {
    this.setState({data: this.props.data})
};


draw = () => {
    let arrArea =[];
    let data = this.state.data;
    console.log(data);
    let values = Object.entries(data);
   let colorCodes = ["#17607D", "#F2D8A7", "#1FCECB", "#FF9311", "#003D5C", "#F27649", "#D5CDB6", "#008C74", "#30588C", "#263138"];
    values.map((x, i) => {
  arrArea.push(<Area type='monotone' dataKey="value" stroke={colorCodes[i]} fill={colorCodes[i]} data={x[1]}/>)
     });
    console.log(arrArea);
return arrArea;
};

render(){
    return(
        <ResponsiveContainer height='100%' width='100%'>
        <AreaChart  data={this.state.data}
                   margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
            <XAxis dataKey="t"/>
            <YAxis/>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
            <Tooltip/>
            <Legend />
            {this.draw().map(x=> x)}
        </AreaChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    )
}
}
```

The second printing statement shows that the Areas are created but the result is only:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913626/react-recharts-getting-data-from-different-objects, this might give you some insight

Comment: Please share your solution as I am facing the same problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was the data set structure, Recharts was expecting structure like this for building the graphs of two values on the same dashboard. Like in the picture above there will be value and valueTwo in the legend not four value:

```
 [  {t: "00:00", value: 0.000957, valueTwo: 0.000185}, 
    {t: "03:00", value: 0.000853, valueTwo:  0.00011},
    {t: "07:00", value: 0.004372, valueTwo: 0.000236},
    {t: "09:00", value: 0.001052, valueTwo: 0.003084},
    {t: "13:00", value: 0.001013, valueTwo: 0.000132},
    {t: "16:00", value: 0.000854, valueTwo: 0.000108},
    {t: "18:00", value: 0.000861, valueTwo: 0.000136},
    {t: "22:00", value: 0.004468, valueTwo: 0.000308}
]
```

Basically, each time point which is a unique point on the graph and the values for it have to be a separate entry in the array.

I hope this helps :)